# how to read data more than 3GB with Java InputStream from middle offset

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have some case here, i try to create download client with apache common httpclient version 4.1. I want to download file from one server ex. http://kambing.ui.ac.id/iso/centos/6.2/isos/i386/CentOS-6.2-i386-bin-DVD1.iso and make the download to partial download (8 or 9 connection). But, I'm stuck at make it partial download...

I think my problem is when reading stream

```
CountingInputStream cis = new CountingInputStream(entity.getContent());
long len = entity.getContentLength();
byte[] bytes = new byte[1024];
int offset = 0;
int numread = 0;
System.out.println(cis.skip(4));
while ((numread = cis.read(bytes, 0, bytes.length)) !=-1){
    System.out.println(cis.getByteCount()+" bytes");
}
```

I was try to set

> > cis.read(bytes, (int) (entity.getContentLength()/2), (int) entity.getContentLength())

But it is error

Any Idea how to make partial download with common-httpclient?

Answer (score 0):

What exactly error is?

> read(bytes, (int) (entity.getContentLength()/2), (int) entity.getContentLength())

Whit your code you're trying to read half of the file immediately.

Maybe you could try something like this:

```
int blockSize = 4096; 

int bytes = 0;
byte[] block = new byte[blockSize];

int offset = entity.getContentLength()/2;
while ((bytes = in.read(block, offset, blockSize) != -1){
        out.write(block, 0, bytes);
        counter += bytes;
        //Exit when you read enougth bytes
        if(counter > MAXIMUM_PART_SIZE){
          break;
        }
}
```

Comment: yupz thankz for your sample...
I never think a counter when it has count to maximum part